# Change symbol size in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How can I make the diodes in the following circuit smaller?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    %\draw[step=1.0,black!20] (0,0) grid (6,4);
    \draw
        (1,1) node[nigfete] (fet1) {}
        (1,3) node[nigfete] (fet2) {}
        (3,1) node[nigfete] (fet3) {}
        (3,3) node[nigfete] (fet4) {}
        (5,1) node[nigfete] (fet5) {}
        (5,3) node[nigfete] (fet6) {};
    \draw
        (fet1.S)++(0,0.4) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet1.D)+(0.5,-0.4)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        (fet2.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet2.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet3.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet3.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet4.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet4.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        (fet5.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet5.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet6.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet6.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0);
    \draw
        (fet1.S)++(0,0) -- ++(-2,0) to[battery] ($(fet2.D)+(-2,0)$) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw 
        (fet1.D) to (fet2.S)
        (fet3.D) to (fet4.S)
        (fet5.D) to (fet6.S);
    \draw 
        (fet1.S) to (fet3.S)
        (fet3.S) to (fet5.S)
        (fet2.D) to (fet4.D)
        (fet4.D) to (fet6.D);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

`to[sD*, scale=.5]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=<value>}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (1,1) node[nigfete] (fet1) {}
        (1,3) node[nigfete] (fet2) {}
        (3,1) node[nigfete] (fet3) {}
        (3,3) node[nigfete] (fet4) {}
        (5,1) node[nigfete] (fet5) {}
        (5,3) node[nigfete] (fet6) {};
    \draw
        (fet1.S)++(0,0.4) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet1.D)+(0.5,-0.4)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        (fet2.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet2.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet3.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet3.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet4.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet4.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        (fet5.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet5.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet6.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet6.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0);
    \draw
        (fet1.S)++(0,0) -- ++(-2,0) to[battery] ($(fet2.D)+(-2,0)$) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw 
        (fet1.D) to (fet2.S)
        (fet3.D) to (fet4.S)
        (fet5.D) to (fet6.S);
    \draw 
        (fet1.S) to (fet3.S)
        (fet3.S) to (fet5.S)
        (fet2.D) to (fet4.D)
        (fet4.D) to (fet6.D);
  \end{circuitikz}

\vspace{10pt}

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.6cm}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (1,1) node[nigfete] (fet1) {}
        (1,3) node[nigfete] (fet2) {}
        (3,1) node[nigfete] (fet3) {}
        (3,3) node[nigfete] (fet4) {}
        (5,1) node[nigfete] (fet5) {}
        (5,3) node[nigfete] (fet6) {};
    \draw
        (fet1.S)++(0,0.4) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet1.D)+(0.5,-0.4)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        (fet2.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet2.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet3.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet3.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet4.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet4.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        (fet5.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet5.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0)        
        (fet6.S)++(0,0.1) -- ++(0.5,0) to[sD*] ($(fet6.D)+(0.5,-0.1)$) -- ++(-0.5,0);
    \draw
        (fet1.S)++(0,0) -- ++(-2,0) to[battery] ($(fet2.D)+(-2,0)$) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw 
        (fet1.D) to (fet2.S)
        (fet3.D) to (fet4.S)
        (fet5.D) to (fet6.S);
    \draw 
        (fet1.S) to (fet3.S)
        (fet3.S) to (fet5.S)
        (fet2.D) to (fet4.D)
        (fet4.D) to (fet6.D);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to scale the whole circuit, you can use the options `scale=<value>,transform shape` to the `circuitikz` environment:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
....
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Gonzalo, many thanks for your answer. Is it possible to make the diodes smaller without changing the size of the battery?

Comment: @sergej You can only change the appearance of the `full Schottky diode` with: `\tikzset{full Schottky diode/.append style={bipoles/length=1cm}}` or `\tikzset{full Schottky diode/.append style={/tikz/every node/.append style={/tikz/scale=0.5}}}`.

Comment: You can also try to put `\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375} 
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}`, or something similar, before your circuit. That will affect all diodes, and only diodes, scaling them down 1/4 of the original.

Comment: I would just like to point out that you can put calls to `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=<value>}` inside your circuitikz environment, interspersed with `\draw` commands, so that different components can have different sizes.

Comment: Even better, you can just do `\draw (0,0) to[R, bipoles/length=0.5cm] (1,0)` if you only need to change the size of a single component.

Comment: The `bipoles/length` doesn't work for MOSFETs though.

Comment: @JasonS: For that you have: ``tripoles/nigfete/height`` and ``tripoles/nigfete/width``.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, with a recent `circuitikz` (> `0.9.4`), you can just do something like that in the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors, EFvoltages]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{diodes/scale=0.5, transistors/scale=1.2}
```

[image: output with scaling]